# Printing "£" on a Star TSP100 usb printer

Tags: printing

I am using TSp100 USb printer but Every time i try to print a British Pound sign (£) i get a funny ß character printed on the receipt instead when using the Star TSB100 USB Printer. I intsalled drivers and all successfully. Also I the last character at right side of receipt is wrap and go to next line. Any hlep ? Thanks.

Comment: Check your language settings

Comment: I select language as "English UK" , also from "Configuration utility" - > general Settings : Set international character set to UK.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].